# insert image on footer and center

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

How can I center inside a footer a img and h1 for the title, I am using JQuery Mobile. I have tryed like this but I can´t:

```
<div data-role="footer" class="footer_menu" data-position=fixed>
    <div class="imagen_pie">

        <img  src="../img/btn_compartir.png" alt="main logo"  style="display:inline"/>
        <h1 class="page_footer">bla bla bla</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
.imagen_pie{
    text-align:center;
}
```

I want center the image and the h1 on footer

![I have apply][1]

Comment: make img and h1 inline-block element

Comment: check my answer. Is that what you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

img is by default an inline-block element. you need to make h1 also inline-block

Here is my [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kA96q/)

```
.imagen_pie{
text-align: center;
}
.imagen_pie h1 {
display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Add image to your jsfiddle and see, it won't align properly as your adding inline-block only to h1. So instead of that margin: auto is a better approach to align. In future if he adds copyrights p tag, it will align at the center. let the solution be future proof and less modificatin

Comment: Thank you so much, it works. But I have one question, how can I align 2 elements to center vertically, I have edited my question with a image.

Comment: @mohamedrias See this Fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/kA96q/3/ it will work. img is an inline-block element by default. you dont need to specify it

Answer (score 0):

Margin: 0 auto for .imagenpie class should do the work

Answer (score 0):

```
.imagen_pie {
     width: 25%;
     margin: auto;
}
```

This will center the imagen_pie div which contains both image and h1.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kA96q/1/)**

Comment: the problem with approach is you need to know the width of your h1 in advance then only you can specify the width of imagen_pie

Answer (score 0):

I will use the `display: inline-block;` as follow:

```
.imagen_pie img, .imagen_pie h1 {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

regards,
yann

Answer (score 0):

```
.imagen_pie {
    text-align: center;
}
.imagen_pie img, .imagen_pie h1 {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Note: Remove inline style on Image tag.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ismailakhtar786/4pLjc/)

regards, Ismail